# This question is a basic optimization problem, also a linear algebra question:

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Let $p$ be a direction of unboundedness for the constraints
$$Ax = b, x ≥ 0.$$
Prove that $−p$ cannot be a direction of unboundedness for these constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I have no formal training in optimization, so I'm sorry if my notation is not standard. Let $S$ be the set of all $x$ whose coordinates are all positive. Then $AS$ is the set $\{Ax:x\in S\}$. For $p$ to be a direction of unboundedness means that $\lambda p\in AS$ for all $\lambda>0$. So we should really try to understand what sort of elements can belong to $AS$.

The way to think about $S$ is that it's trying very hard to be a vector space, but it only allows positive coefficients when you break up a vector into its basis components. That is, if $y\in S$ then we can break it into $y=y_1e_1+y_2e_2+\cdots+y_ne_n$, where $e_1=(1,0,0,\dots,0)$, $e_2=(0,1,0,\dots,0)$, etc. where $y_k\geq 0$ for all $k$.

How can we use this to gain a clearer picture about what is in $AS$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a primal (P) linear program (LP) and its corresponding dual (D) LP:
$$
P: \min~c^{T}x~~~~~D:\max p^{T}b\\
Ax=b~~~~~~~p^{T}A\leq{c}^{T}\\
x\geq0~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$$
Weak duality ($c^{T}x \geq p^{T}b$) implies that when primal is unbounded ($c^{T}x=-\infty$) the dual is infeasible ($c^{T}-p^{T}A \ngeq 0$) and vice versa. Changing the direction of $c$ affects the optimality of the primal. Since the feasibility region in standard form ($Ax=b$ and $x\geq0$) does not contain a line, $-c^{T}x$ is either finite and optimimum ($c^{T}x^{*}=p^{*T}b$) or infeasible.